# How to delete a row from CLOB (plsql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created a function that generates a CLOB.

But this CLOB contains a line that I have to delete.

How can I do that? (I tried the `TRIM` keyword but I think it didn't work)

Comment: maybe replace('line of code','')

Comment: Please structure your question in a way that will show: #1 - Your current work, #2 - Your current output, #3 - Your desired output. Your question at the moment is very vague, which means it will be hard for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

A clob does not truly contain "lines" as such, it is just a stream of characters. So I'm assuming you are attaching some meaning to the characters, eg, the clob might contain something like:

```
A world of dew,
And within every dewdrop
A world of struggle.
```

and you want to remove (say) the second "line".  The clob itself is going to be:

```
A world of dew,[carriage return]And within every dewdrop[carriage return]A world of struggle.
```

and this may vary depending on platform / characterset (eg Windows might have a carriage return AND a line feed).

In any event, you would use DBMS_LOB.INSTR to hunt for the positions of carriage returns etc, and then use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR to produce a clob which strips out the content you want to retain